# Data type mismatch in criteria expression for Access AutoNumber

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
RentReturnCommand.CommandText = "update CustomerOrder set Status = '" &_ OrderStatusComboBox.Text & "' WHERE  CID = " & CIDTextBox.Text & "  AND CompID = " &_ CompIDText.Text

RentReturnCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

`RentReturnCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` constantly shows up as the error.

I've looked up all possible solutions to change this, but nothing works. My CID is listed in Access Database as an AutoNumber.

I know AutoNumber tends to cause a problem with this type of SQL involved, but I really need to query that in my program.

Comment: "CurrentDB" is not valid

Comment: Ignore that, for some reason I thought this was Access front end.

Comment: so keep it as just "update CustomerOrder set Status = '" & OrderStatusComboBox.Text & "' WHERE CID = " & CIDTextBox.Text & " AND CompID = " & CompIDText.Text

Answer (score 1):

If I type "fred" in your textbox, this error will take place.  Two things that will help you are  validating all user input and using query parameters.